# $ord\:\alpha=lcm(ord\theta_1,...,ord \theta_m)$ proof

Tags: group-theory

> **Proposition**: If $\alpha\in S_n$(group of permutations). If $\alpha$ is the product of $\alpha=\theta_1...\theta_m$ of disjoint cycles, so $ord\:\alpha=lcm(ord\theta_1,...,ord \theta_m)$.
>
> (*ord* reads order, and *lcm* stands for the least  common multiple).

$k\in\mathbb{N}\:,\:\alpha^k=(\theta_1...\theta_m)^k=\theta_1^k...\theta_m^k$

$\alpha^k=id\:\:\:\text{iff}\:\:\:\theta_1^k...\theta^k_m=id\:\:\:\text{iff}\:\:\:\theta_1^k=...=\theta^k_m=id$. I am stuck at this point.

**Question:**

How do I procede to finish the proof? How do I integrate the least minimum multiple in the proof?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

$\theta_i^k=\operatorname{id}\iff k\;$ is a multiple of $\;\operatorname{ord}(\theta_i)$.

What is the smallest possible value for $k$?